# Why does my dragover event prevent my drop event from firing?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

i'm tring to create a drag and drop in a football website.
the drop event dosen' t fire and i don't know why.

this is the code where i create the span whith name of the player and where i setup the event.

```
let spanAttaccanti = document.createElement("span");
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragstart", onDragStart);
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragend",dragEnd)
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragover", ondragover);
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragenter", ondragenter);
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragleave", onDragLeave);
      spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("drop", ondrop);
    spanAttaccanti.setAttribute("draggable", true);
    spanAttaccanti.setAttribute("id", arrAttccanti[0][i]);
    spanAttaccanti.innerHTML = arrAttccanti[0][i];
    divAttacco2.appendChild(spanAttaccanti);
```

and this is the function for the event.

```
let dragedItem   

function onDragStart(event){
  console.log("inizio")
  setTimeout(()=>this.classList.add("hidden"),0)
   dragedItem=this
  
}
function dragEnd(event) { 
  dragedItem=null
}
function ondragover(e) {
  console.log("hover");
  
  e.preventDefault()
}
function onDrop(event) {
  console.log("drop");
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

the proble is that the event `onDrop` never fire.
[my Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMpyq.png)

please help

I' m a noob of js and i'm starting to learning this langauage
i create a small snipper to better understanding the problem

```js
function creaSquadre(idSquadra1){
 let squadra1 = document.getElementById(idSquadra1);

 arrAttccanti = [
      ["example1", "example2", "example3", "example4"],
      ["4", "4", "1", "1"],
    ];
    
     let divAttacco2 = document.createElement("div");
  divAttacco2.className = "divAttacco";

  squadra1.appendChild(divAttacco2);

  for (let i = 0; i < arrAttccanti[0].length; i++) {
    let spanAttaccanti = document.createElement("span");
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragstart", onDragStart);
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragend",dragEnd)
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragover", ondragover);
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragenter", ondragenter);
    spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("dragleave", onDragLeave);
      spanAttaccanti.addEventListener("drop", ondrop);
    spanAttaccanti.setAttribute("draggable", true);
    spanAttaccanti.setAttribute("id", arrAttccanti[0][i]);
    spanAttaccanti.innerHTML = arrAttccanti[0][i];
    divAttacco2.appendChild(spanAttaccanti);
  }
 }
 
 let dragedItem   

function onDragStart(event){
  console.log("inizio")
  setTimeout(()=>this.classList.add("hidden"),0)
   dragedItem=this
  
}
function dragEnd(event) { 
  dragedItem=null
}

function ondragover(e) {
  console.log("hover");
  
  e.preventDefault()
}
function onDragEnter(event) {
  console.log("entrato");
}
function onDragLeave(event) {
  console.log("uscito");
}
function onDrop(event) {
  console.log("drop");
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<body onload="creaSquadre('squadra1')">
 </section>
        <section id="squadra1" class="squadra1">
</body>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Why is there JS code in between the <sup> tag?

Comment: Another question: where are you calling all these functions? Can you add additional code to help us understand your issue?

Comment: I think drop event gets triggered on the element on which the dragged element is dropped. So you need to listed for the event on the element on which `spanAttaccanti` will be dropped

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: is important that every span can be swapped whit every span. this is the reason why i put the event onDrop in all of span

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have issues with the naming of two of the functions. That side you can simplify thing by setting the event listeners on the parent `<div>`. And then you need to test where the `<span>` is dropped (like `if (target.nodeName == 'SPAN' && source != target) {`).

Also make use of the `event.dataTransfer` object instead of creating a global variable.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let squadra1 = document.getElementById(e.target.body.dataset.squadra);

  squadra1.addEventListener("dragstart", onDragStart);
  squadra1.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd)
  squadra1.addEventListener("dragover", ondragover);
  squadra1.addEventListener("dragenter", onDragEnter);
  squadra1.addEventListener("dragleave", onDragLeave);
  squadra1.addEventListener("drop", onDrop);

  let arrAttccanti = [
    ["example1", "example2", "example3", "example4"],
    ["4", "4", "1", "1"],
  ];

  let divAttacco2 = document.createElement("div");
  divAttacco2.className = "divAttacco";

  squadra1.appendChild(divAttacco2);

  arrAttccanti[0].forEach((attaccanti, i) => {
    let spanAttaccanti = document.createElement("span");
    spanAttaccanti.setAttribute("draggable", true);
    spanAttaccanti.setAttribute("id", attaccanti);
    spanAttaccanti.innerHTML = attaccanti;
    divAttacco2.appendChild(spanAttaccanti);
  });
});

//let dragedItem

function onDragStart(event) {
  console.log("inizio");
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
}

function dragEnd(event) {
  console.log("end");
}

function ondragover(e) {
  console.log("hover");
  e.preventDefault();
}

function onDragEnter(event) {
  console.log("entrato");
}

function onDragLeave(event) {
  console.log("uscito");
}

function onDrop(event) {
  console.log("drop");
  event.preventDefault();
  let source = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  let target = event.target.closest('span');
  if (target.nodeName == 'SPAN' && source != target) {
    let targetClone = target.cloneNode(true);
    source.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', targetClone);
    target.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', source);
    target.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<body data-squadra="squadra1">
  <section id="squadra1" class="squadra1"></section>
</body>
```